# Customized navigation Back Button in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code in app delegate.m to set back button image on navigation bar, but its displaying 3 buttons instead of one..

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_icon.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]
                                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-100,0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And if I use the following code, it stretches the back button:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_icon.png"]
                                                      forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-100,0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the issue of `UIEdgeInsetsMake` value, because using that you are trying to repeat the background image, try like this

```
UIImage *gradientImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage32 forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside
                                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: text is displayed instead of image using this solution. What I want is to show back image instead of default back button on navigation bar.